# Trying to add multiple graphs to one plot in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, charts

I'm trying to make a graph that shows cost and effectiveness tradeoffs between multiple different solutions using ggplot2. I can make the graph I want for one solution, but I can't figure out how to add more solutions into the same graph.

This code works, for one solution:

```
library(ggplot2)

data_test = data.frame(x = c(100,102,103),          # Create example data frame
               y1 = c(30, 15, 30),
               y2 = c(30, 80, 30))

ggp = ggplot(data_test, aes(x = x)) +    
  geom_line(aes(y = y1)) +
  geom_line(aes(y = y2))
ggp                                 

ggp +                              
  geom_ribbon(aes(x = x,
              ymin = y1,
              ymax = y2),
          fill = "#1b98e0") +
  geom_segment(aes(x = 100, y = 30, xend = 103, yend = 30, colour = "blue")) +
  geom_segment(aes(x = 102, y = 15, xend = 102, yend = 80, colour = "blue"))
```

Now, I'd like to add a second plot onto the same graph using the data_test2 (below) for the second solution,, but I can't figure out how to do this.

```
data_test2 = data.frame(x = c(106,112,120),          # Create example data frame
               y1 = c(20, 3, 20),
               y2 = c(20, 76, 20))
```

I've tried looking at other packages to combine plots, but nothing seems to put them together in one frame.

Answer (score 1):

You could combine the two datasets into one using `bind_rows()` from the `dplyr` package. In this example I named the datasets `A` and `B` in a new id column named `dataset`. By mapping this new column to the `fill` aesthetic, the resulting ribbons are colored by dataset.

```r
library(ggplot2)

df <- dplyr::bind_rows('A' = data_test, 'B' = data_test2, .id = 'dataset')
df
#>   dataset   x y1 y2
#> 1       A 100 30 30
#> 2       A 102 15 80
#> 3       A 103 30 30
#> 4       B 106 20 20
#> 5       B 112  3 76
#> 6       B 120 20 20
```

```r
ggplot(df, aes(x = x, fill = dataset)) +    
  geom_line(aes(y = y1)) +
  geom_line(aes(y = y2)) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(x = x,
                  ymin = y1,
                  ymax = y2)) +
  geom_segment(aes(x = 100, y = 30, xend = 103, yend = 30, colour = "blue")) +
  geom_segment(aes(x = 102, y = 15, xend = 102, yend = 80, colour = "blue"))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2024-03-20 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Like the existing answer by Seth, this combines into one data frame. I think though you also need to create another data frame for the `geom_segment()` calls, otherwise you have to provide absolute values for each segment which doesn't scale well with lots of shapes. I've done the combining in base R:

```r
dat  <- rbind(
    transform(data_test, src = "data_test1"),
    transform(data_test2, src = "data_test2")
)

segments  <- aggregate(
    list(x = dat$x, y1 = dat$y1, y2 = dat$y2),
    by = list(dat$src), \(x) c(min = min(x), max = max(x), med = median(x))) |>
    do.call(data.frame, args = _)
```

Then rather than providing absolute values to each `geom_segment()`, you can provide the relevant values from the `segments` data frame:

```r
ggplot(dat, aes(x = x, color = src)) +    
  geom_line(aes(y = y1)) +
  geom_line(aes(y = y2)) +                 
  geom_ribbon(aes(x = x,
              ymin = y1,
              ymax = y2,
              fill = src)) +
  geom_segment(
    data = segments, 
    aes(x = x.min, xend = x.max, y = y2.min, yend = y1.max), color = "blue") +
  geom_segment(
    data = segments, 
    aes(x = x.med, xend = x.med, y = y1.min, yend = y2.max), color = "blue") +
    theme_minimal() +
    theme(
        legend.title = element_blank(),
        legend.position = "bottom"
    )
```

[image]